# Exception "No file usage (sys_file_reference) found for given UID." when copying a TYPO3 page

Tags: typo3, backend, typo3-6.2.x

[image: Exception "No file usage (sys_file_reference) found for given UID."]
Anybody here that knows that error message? It appears when I try to copy a page in TYPO3 6.2.26.

The error only appears when there is a image relation in the page properties. After removing the relation, the page can be copied without error message.

Furthermore, when this exception appears, the page tree isn't updated properly. The copy shows the same page ID and title (without the "copy 1). You need to manually update the page tree.

Comment: Is the image relation valid (not broken) and is the reference index up to date?

Comment: Yes, I've tested that with a freshly created page. Beforehand I've updated the refindex via CLI.

Comment: Can you check whether this might be related to https://forge.typo3.org/issues/60754 and potentially to https://forge.typo3.org/issues/63353 ?

Comment: @Susi the patch from https://forge.typo3.org/issues/63353 didn't work for me.

Comment: Are you using workspaces / multi language?

Comment: In this project I use neither workspaces nor multi language.

Comment: I have no idea left, I just took a look at the relevant code (ResourceFactory::getFileReferenceObject) - if you could provide a t3d or something for me to reproduce the issue I'd go and debug it.